# URL removal of entire domain from Google

Tags: google-search

I would like to clean up a domain's results from Google.

I developed a Website for a Client X and I hosted it in my server with a subdomain.

After I finished the development process, I proceeded to move the entire website from my server to the client's server (With a different domain and everything)

The problem: If I search for content of the Website in Google, I still watching my domain (Both search and images results)

I sent "the removal request" to Google. They said that the pages were deleted, but if I search, I still watching my domain.

Thanks for your help.

P.S.: I put the robots.txt file, I submitted the XML Map, etc. But nothing works.

- Sorry about my english *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you need to do:

1. Use the Google Change of Address tool
2. Repoint the old domain name to the new domain name using a 301 Redirect
3. Wait a few days for Google to recrawl the site

Visit https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83106?hl=en which details how to access and use the Change of Address tool.

Additionally, set a 301 redirect from the old address on your server, to the new address. You could even do this at the server level ("oh, received request for dev.xyz.com/some/page? I'll have to 301 redirect it to xyz.com/some/page").

As for the waiting a few days, just gotta give Google's spiders time to recrawl. Could be a few hours, could be a few days.

Edit: Additionally, please check Google's moving checklist: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/83105

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try it immediately.

Comment: Certainly! If you feel this answer was helpful, please don't forget to upvote/select as best! :)